Flink - How to convert table result to Datastream
i was trying to query a postgresql table, and convert it to dataStream:
StreamExecutionEnvironment bsEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(bsEnv);
                .
                .
                .
                .
            catalog config and register
                .
                .
                .
Table tb = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable);
DataStream<Row> dataStream = tEnv.toDataStream(tb)  
dataStream.print();

But it seems that the datastream is empty..
the query is fine , when i print the TableResult i can see my table.
TableResult tb1 = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable).execute();
tb1.print();

                     

is this the right way to do it?
i wondered because according to Table doc:
"A Table object describes a pipeline of data transformations. It does not contain the data itself in any way."
so if its not containing the data, what the point by convert it to datastream?
or maybe the datastream supposed to hold the data?
i also tried to convert the TableResult to DataStream but didn't find a proper way to do it.
thank you!

Do you have env.execute(); in your code ?
If you not executing StreamExecutionEnvironment you'll not have any results.
// create environments of both APIs
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

...

// add a printing sink and execute in DataStream API
resultStream.print();
env.execute();

Example in Flink doc
